# html meta tag not detecting device width?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I have searched and searched and I can not seem to find a reason why my html meta tag is not working on my iPhone. You can visit my website at http://hadenhiles.mooo.com. If you resize the viewport (window) you will see that my site responds totally as expected... however when you view it on a mobile device you get a result that looks as though it is a desktop version. here is the **head tag** and it's contents:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

As you likely have noticed I use my own stylesheet as well as the bootstrap3 stylesheet. I know I should likely stick to one or the other when it comes to layout but I made this website using only my own media queries before I was introduced to bootstrap. I only use bootstrap in the footer and for popups/navbar features. Anyway bootstrap is not the issue. ***It seems as though the meta tag is not recognizing the device width and is not setting the initial scale to 1.0***. I have tried varying the **min-width** of my queries to debug but had no success. Here is are my **css media queries**:

```
/* Main css */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 320px){
    /* content */
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 600px){
    /* content */
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 768px){
    /* content */
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 1020px){
    /* content */
}
```

I have tried switching from **@media only screen and** to **@media screen** as someone suggested in another question but had no success either. At first I thought that the min/max width was too big/small for mobile devices so I changed that and nothing happened. I have had this problem for about 3 months now so I decided to publish my own question. Any help you can give me is much appreciated.

~Haden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this isn't exactly defining what's going on, although I do think that it is due to min and max conflicts. Try setting only max-width since that seems to be covering everything. It seems redundant to say min-width is 1px and max width is 320px and then for the next media query to be 321px. If you set the max-width to 320px, it will cover that range. If you set the next one to 600 pixels, it will cover the 320-600 range, etc.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px){
    /* content */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
 /* content */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
    /* content */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1020px){
    /* content */
}
```

Alternatively, you might try using **min-device-width** and **max-device-width**. Here's a link to a decent resource on [media queries for standard devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

Comment: Sorry for not defining the problem clearly..none the less you solved my problem! Thank you so much.

Comment: Or maybe not... it works fine when I test the website locally using xCode iPhone emulator, however when I load the website on the internet it doesn't respond the same.. hmmm.

Comment: Try viewing the non-cloaked version on your device. Something about the free redirection service is messing up your media queries. Likely because it's encasing the entire site inside of a frame and devices don't handle iframes/frames very well. I would be willing to bet that if you moved this to a dedicated server so that your weren't redirecting, it would work as you expect it to.